# Fedora Spins work on ubuntu or not?

Tags: installation, fedora

I want to run the fedora spins, but on Ubuntu. Ubuntu is way much lighter than the fedora versions, but it is their spin that I am interested in. Is any spin like thing is available on Ubuntu? If not then are fedora spins capable of running on Ubuntu?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here exactly. Fedora spins are not just applications, but full operating systems. Similar to Ubuntu derivatives. So is the KDE Fedora spin in Ubuntu the Kubuntu distribution, likewise LXDE -> Lubuntu. Unless you're asking which derivatives of Ubuntu there are, this question does not make sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

Fedora spins are absolutely incapable of running on ubuntu, sorry mate :/, what spin do you want exactly ? maybe we can help you find something similar for ubuntu :) ?
[Maybie this will help](http://distrowatch.com/search.php?ostype=Linux&category=All&origin=All&basedon=Ubuntu&notbasedon=None&desktop=All&architecture=All&status=Active)

Answer (score 0):

Fedora spins are nothing else than a simple fedora with pre-installed software packages. You can install packages by yourself via Software center or via command line. Once you will have list of your favorite software (spin) it is just about adding some repositories and one install command

how to add app repository you can read here (), mostly used commnad:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:<repository-name>
sudo apt-get update
```

Install software packages with

```
sudo apt-get install application1 application2 ... applicationN
```

unfortunatelly, I do not know any activity like this going on Ubuntu. Each can be free to install whatever he wants.